# Windows Phone 8 and D3DCompiler

Tags: windows-phone-8, directx-11

For now in windows RT it is possible to access D3DCompiler.h, but application will not pass the store test (this is corrected in windows 8.1).

Is there a way to add D3DCompiler in windows phone project? (Mostly I need reflection support, shaders are generally precompiled). I tried to add the ARM build reference but it doens't seem it wants to include it (some xap security?).

Please note that for now I don't need store deployments, so if it works for development purposes that's fine (and either c++/sharpDX solution is pretty welcomed).

Comment: You probably should rewrite your own reflection layer as a preprocess over the original shader bytecodes and strip the d3d one to keep bytecodes as small as possible ( it is also more complexe to reverse engineer a shader when the information is stripped as it removes resource names ).

Comment: That's what I thought, stripping shader in my use case is not important, having dynamic reflection is much more (I do mostly authoring/tools). Sounds like gonna reinvent the wheel and push bytecode+some script then. Thanks tho )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3DCompiler was not available for 'production' use with Windows Store apps for Windows 8.0 or Windows phone 8.0. It was available for development, but the D3DCompiler #46 DLL itself will not pass the WACK tool for submission to the store.

It is available with Windows Store apps for Windows 8.1 and Windows phone 8.1. The D3DCompiler #47 DLL is included as part of the OS now. See this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile.aspx) post.